# Why is the paint bulging away from my drywall ceiling?

Tags: drywall, kitchens, ceiling

The attached picture shows what's behind a "blob" of paint that seemingly delaminated from my ceiling kitchen right adjacent to the hood that's over the stove.

The paint delaminated during a period of two weeks when noone was home, noone was using the stovetop or the HVAC, etc.  At first, I thought water had pooled in that spot as a result of a leak, but when I cut the bottom-most part of the paint blob off, there was no water and no real sign of recent water intrusion.

It looks like the drywall/plaster/(what is it?) that is proximate to the paint layer is crumbling, and the crumbled pieces caused the layer of paint to "delaminate."

Does this look like water damage to people?  Or some other problem?  I don't even know who to call to take a look at it in person, and my main goal asking here is to figure out what kind of specialist or contractor that would be.

Thank you!

The original "blob" of delaminated paint:
[[image: The original "blob" of delaminated paint]]

After cutting the paint off:
[image: After cutting the dangling "blob" of paint]

Comment: Thanks for looking @keshlam!  I added a few more photos.  "Suspended ceiling" might very well be the wrong term.  What I mean is that in between what we see in the photo and the "real" ceiling is some empty space where the HVAC duct and some electrical runs.   Could very well be standard plasterboard--that is useful information for me.

Comment: Was the ceiling plastered shortly before painting? It needs considerable time (and ventilation) to dry properly.

Comment: Was this recently painted/replastered?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  It was not repainted within the last two years, which is how long I have been in this place; and the paint coming off is a development from the last month or so.  I have no way to find out when it was painted before I moved in.

Comment: (Also, because I wasn't living here when the work was done, I don't know if enough time was allowed between the plaster being put down and the painting.  It sure seems possible that they rushed it, if it was part of a kitchen remodel.)

Comment: Definitely water. Notice the line of discoloration parallel to the cabinet fronts - that appears to be a joint between drywall sheets. A skim coat of compound ("mud") was used to create the slight texturing before painting. Note that the actual leak could be some distance away, since water is much more likely to run "downhill" to the edge of a sheet and seep through the joint than to soak through the drywall itself.

Comment: Fred, that's a keen observation.  I think there are at least three potential sources of water-- roof (above the utility space is a concrete rooftop deck), HVAC ducts (I'm in southern California and since this is below a surface exposed to sun, it seems possible that it could be condensation when using AC), and the hood duct (it opens to a covered chimney, but it seems possible for rain water to come in anyway).  Someone suggested a moisture meter, which I will look into.  To figure this out, is my only option to basically rip the space open and look for signs of water intrusion?

Answer (score 8):

This definitely looks like water damage to me, Latex paint in particular, as its name implies, is elastic/rubbery, and can hold together pretty well when being pushed from behind, producing this effect. That's a rather extreme example, but if it happens, it must be possible.

I suppose air pressure could do it too, though I don't know where you'd get enough air pressure. If it was just the plaster failing for some reason, I wouldn't expect to see such a smooth dome, though I could be wrong.

Above the paint, my guess is plaster over concrete... But that is strictly a guess.

As to where the water went, if it was water... I don't have a good guess. How long were you away between the last time the ceiling looked normal and when you saw the damage?

Comment: It is an interesting picture.  It doesn't have any staining which would normally define water damage.   I would have assumed the same thing but expected to see some yellowish staining.    To me it looks like some sort of extreme temperature spike escaped there...  Like there was something in the ceiling or maybe the ceiling itself got extremely hot (maybe cold).    I will say this... It had to be so gratifying to pop that paint zit.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of staining along one seam, but... Yeah.

Comment: these are my favorite questions.    You could be right but to what degree?    A normal leak wouldn't make that.   What would?

Comment: From what I can see in the second pic, the plaster itself has failed - we can see two or three distinct layers that have dropped, so the paint hasn't failed, quite the reverse, it was only the paint that was holding things together originally.

Comment: I believe we have a consensus here that the blob was caused by water. The source of the water is the question.  A surgical incursion into the ceiling may give the answer.

Comment: I was away for about a week.  In addition to HVAC ducting, the hood also has a duct in that space (it's actually partially visible in the photos).  The hood obviously vents to the outside.  On the air pressure theory, I wonder if the hood duct might have a crack or fissure in it?

Comment: I did notice the slightly brown staining.  But since I cut into the paint within a week of this happening, I would have expected to see at least a droplet of water or two if in fact water caused the problem.  And would that be enough time for staining to occur?  (Though, I suppose if there is a leak, the staining might be from earlier moisture that didn't yet cause the "blob").

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely some discoloration showing on the lower left (in 2nd attached pic). This looks like a water leak to me. If there is nothing but electrical and HVAC up in that utility space (and any space above that), I would be thinking roof leak.

Comment: This may well be due to water damage, but neither picture shows anything definite. Use of a moisture meter would be useful.